# ADO.NET Insert Mysql, All data is null

Tags: mysql, ado.net, null

I have created a winform application, and use ado.net to access mysql database. But I encountered a strange problem.

my data table create script:

```
create table using_user {
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
 'dx_ip_addr' default NULL,
 'scard_type' default NULL,
 ....
}
```

my c# code:

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost; Port=9999; Uid=root; Pwd=ecsc; Database=zhz-netbar-jk;"

conn.Open();

MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "insert into using_user (dx_ip_addr, scard_type,...)values(@dx_ip_addr, @scard_type,...)";

cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@dx_ip_addr", "5000230001"));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@scard_type", "1"));
...

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

conn.Close();
```

After do this,  the primary key 'id' was generated, but other fields are NULL. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: please specify data types to remaining two columns.dx_ip_addr ,scard_type

Comment: All kinds of problems with your code. You're missing data types on the database end. You're also missing the data types on the C# side as well (at the cmd.Parameters.Add line. Also, I assume this isn't production code, but you should really be using the "using" directive on all your Sql objects to make sure they get closed correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem on your table structure where you don't have specified what datatype you will use on the other fields

```
create table using_user {
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
 'dx_ip_addr' default NULL,  <--- no data type specified  
 'scard_type' default NULL,  <--- no data type specified
 ....
}
```

Try

```
 create table using_user {
     `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
     'dx_ip_addr' int,
     'scard_type' int,  
     ....
    }
```

Regards

Comment: Thank you! The fatal error is prefix of my parameter "@dx_ip_addr", MySql has the specify prefix "?". So when I have changed all characters "@" to "?", every thing was ok. Thanks again!